# Code builds and runs, but shows red squiggles. using CMAKE in vs code, C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, makefile, build

i have just started to use vscode and CMAKE. and to learn this i have made a simple project in this regard

My code builds and runs, however the red squiggles does not seem to go away. what should i do, is it still a stable program??

project structure:

|CMakeLists.txt

|App

+---CMakeLists.txt

+---main.cpp

|Source_DIR

+---CMakeLists.txt

+---src

------+---helloworld.cpp

+---include

------+---helloworld.h

toplevel cmakelists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.15...3.18)

project(Project_RetroTron VERSION 1.0.0) 

add_subdirectory(source_DIR)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
add_subdirectory(app)
```

source_DIR/cmakelists.txt:

```
add_library(hello_world 
src/helloworld.cpp)

target_include_directories(hello_world PUBLIC PUBLIC 
$<BUILD_INTERFACE:${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include>)
```

source_DIR/include/helloworld.h

```
#ifndef HELLOWORLD_H
#define HELLOWORLD_H

class helloWorld
{
public:
    helloWorld();    
};

#endif
```

source_DIR/src/helloworld.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "helloworld.h"



helloWorld::helloWorld()
{
std::cout <<"hello my man" << std::endl;
}
```

app/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_executable(helloworldMain main.cpp)


target_link_libraries(helloworldMain PRIVATE hello_world)
```

app/main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "helloworld.h"
int main()
{
helloWorld heya;   
}
```

i also use cmake-tools which generates this .vscode folder with a settings.JSON file on the top level of the hiearchy:

```
{
"C_Cpp.default.configurationProvider": "ms-vscode.cmake-tools"
}
```

used vscode on windows. the build have been erased and rerun so it does not have any old files to refer to.

**why do i still have an error!!!**

this is the result of a build and run, adn as you can see it runs fine:

[cmake make generation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wlpXL.png)

[build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w8c8b.png)

[run](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zc8wW.png)

[still it shows error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JmH2e.png)

[image: project folder structure better visualized]

Comment: Don't run cmake yourself, you have to let the cmake tools plugin run it https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/CMake-linux